# ValueError when filling pandas dataframe cell with Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

The goal is to make a Pandas Series where every element is a variable-length numpy array.  These arrays come from a function `getContexts`, which gets the masked results of one dataframe `cnv` and applies it to another dataframe `exp`.  This is done twice: once for the `True` (loss), and once for the `False` (no_loss) condition.  The error I get is `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence` occurring at the second line in `getContexts`.

Here is are some test data to try out:

```
deldf = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,0,1],
                     [1,0,1,0],
                     [1,1,1,0]])
deldf.columns = ['a','b','c','d']
deldf['cnv'] = ['k','l','m']
deldf.set_index(deldf['cnv'], inplace=True, drop=True)
del deldf['cnv']

d_mask = deldf == 1

expdf = pd.DataFrame([[0,2,1,4,np.array([1,1,1])],
                     [10,0,12,1,np.array([2,2,2])],
                     [1,1,1,1,np.array([3,3,3])]])
expdf.columns = ['a','b','c','d','arr']
expdf['exp'] = ['x','y','Z']
expdf.set_index(expdf['exp'], inplace=True, drop=True)
del expdf['exp']

results = pd.DataFrame(dels.index)
results['exp'] = expdf.index
results.columns = ['cnv','exp']
```

Here is my attempt at the solution (note that d_mask is a global variable):

```
def getContexts(exp_g, cnv_gm):
    lossTrue = d_mask.loc[cnv_g]
    # error is thrown at line below
    loss = np.array(expdf.loc[exp_g].where(lossTrue, np.nan).dropna())
    no_loss = np.array(expdf.loc[exp_g].where(~lossTrue, np.nan).dropna())
    return loss, no_loss
```

Here is my call to `getContexts`:

```
results['loss'], results['no_loss'] = np.vectorize(getContexts)(results['exp'], results['cnv'])
```

The end result should look like the dataframe below, so that I can check variance, length, mean, and effect-size on the two columns of arrays.
[image]

Comment: Which line is causing your error and how do you use the getContexts function?

Comment: @Allen function call and line of error was added to the question.  Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You code seems to have some reference errors. After I changed dels to deldf and cnv_g to cnv_gm, it's no longer throwing errors.

```
deldf = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,0,1],
                     [1,0,1,0],
                     [1,1,1,0]])
deldf.columns = ['a','b','c','d']
deldf['cnv'] = ['k','l','m']
deldf.set_index(deldf['cnv'], inplace=True, drop=True)
del deldf['cnv']

d_mask = deldf == 1

expdf = pd.DataFrame([[0,2,1,4,np.array([1,1,1])],
                     [10,0,12,1,np.array([2,2,2])],
                     [1,1,1,1,np.array([3,3,3])]])
expdf.columns = ['a','b','c','d','arr']
expdf['exp'] = ['x','y','Z']
expdf.set_index(expdf['exp'], inplace=True, drop=True)
del expdf['exp']

results = pd.DataFrame(deldf.index)
results['exp'] = expdf.index
results.columns = ['cnv','exp']

def getContexts(exp_g, cnv_gm):
    lossTrue = d_mask.loc[cnv_gm]
    # error is thrown at line below
    loss = np.array(expdf.loc[exp_g].where(lossTrue, np.nan).dropna())
    no_loss = np.array(expdf.loc[exp_g].where(~lossTrue, np.nan).dropna())
    return loss, no_loss

results['loss'], results['no_loss'] = np.vectorize(getContexts)(results['exp'], results['cnv'])
print(results)

  cnv exp       loss no_loss
0   k   x     [2, 4]  [0, 1]
1   l   y   [10, 12]  [0, 1]
2   m   Z  [1, 1, 1]     [1]
```